# No Supported Authentification Methods AWS EC2 Instance with PuTTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I am a newbie to SSH and want to connect to my AWS EC2 instance using PuTTY to host a Discord bot. I have generated a RSA private key using the EC2 guide and have configured PuTTY as far as importing private keys and entering hostname.

I am pretty sure I entered the information right that I got from EC2. I'm not really sure if I can get log files either. I have seen other issues like this but no one seemed to be using AWS.

Comment: you will have to provide exacly step by step what did you do,  how do you connect (are you sure you are using the right user, keypair,.. ), and what images do you use, otherwise nobody would be able to help you (without connecting you won't get any logs). https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/17385-use-putty-to-access-ec2-linux-instances-via-ssh-from-windows

Comment: This post can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Answer (score 0):

Redownloaded the .pem file. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks